# How can i open all ports of EndPoints Linux on Windows Azure

Tags: linux, azure, endpoints

I have an application that run MPIRUN on linux cluster using the Windows Azure, mpirun needs the following specs to run through my cluster:

1. Keyless SSH.
2. disabling the firewall of linux
3. opening all ports of EndPionts because that mpirun is not using static ports.

the issue is that i need to open all ports but Windows Azure supports 100 port only, so is there any method to support mpirun on cluster of linux nodes.

The following output when i ran my mpicode on my linux cluster:

```
Daemon was launched on ahmed-Sate3781 - beginning to initialize
Daemon [[4241,0],2] checking in as pid 1585 on host ahmed-Sate3781
Daemon [[4241,0],2] not using static ports
Daemon was launched on ahmed-Sate3780 - beginning to initialize
Daemon [[4241,0],1] checking in as pid 1703 on host ahmed-Sate3780
Daemon [[4241,0],1] not using static ports
[ahmed-Sate3780:01703] [[4241,0],1] orted: up and running - waiting for commands
```

!

thanks,

Comment: The ports you need to open, are those to accept connections from outside of the azure hosted cluster? Or just for connections from other VM's within that cloud service? If the later, there's no need to open up the endpoints as connections between VMs within the same cloud service or virtual network are not restricted.

Comment: i need to make the VMs communicate to each other, mpi has a service called orted which generate random ports not a static ports to listen on, also every VM has a single cloud service not the same. pleas i need any help urgently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigations, i found that i need to create all linux virtual machines within the same cloud service or within the same virtual network on Windows Azure. Azure provides VMs within the same cloud service to communicate to each other without need to open ports. so mpirun will work